# There was a problem with mariadb and docker connection

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

```sh
# command
docker run --name mariadb -d -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mariadb mariadb
```

```sh
# errors
cdccf021df19929bc8b3783c589234b1515d8afd05beeaba00e0e9157f458c73
docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

I want to connect with `mariadb`, but I can't fix this error. Please help me.

Comment: Are you trying to run a database server, or a client?  If you're trying to connect to another database server, you don't need the `-p` option; that's to accept inbound connections.  (You don't even need Docker for this; you can use the `mariadb` or `mysql` client on your host.)

Answer (score 0):

Yeh seems to be have port already in use by another process.

Use below command to check if port in  use already.

```
netstat -an | grep :3306
```